# Sending a multipart form-data request to debug my AWS Lambda function, via AWS toolkit

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, multipartform-data, aws-toolkit

I am developer of an AWS Lambda function, that I'm in the process of converting from a command-line app, written in Groovy.

I have the Function uploaded and set up on AWS Lambda console, complete with an API Gateway endpoint that, when `POST`ed to, will run the Function. This Function also is connected to an EFS file system.

However, when I hit that endpoint with a request from Postman, it doesn't work. I view the logs and get see an exception over a piece of code that is a file util method that works on a user's computer (assuming the app runs on, and writes files in the file system that is on, their computer), but doesn't seem to work on the EFS:

```
No such file or directory: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at java_io_File$createNewFile$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at com.mikebuyshouses.dncscrubber.utils.FileUtils.CreateFileIfNotExists(FileUtils.groovy:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at com.mikebuyshouses.dncscrubber.awsServices.ApiRequestHandler$_parseRequestEvent_closure1.doCall(ApiRequestHandler.groovy:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2331)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2316)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2357)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$202.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at com.mikebuyshouses.dncscrubber.awsServices.ApiRequestHandler.parseRequestEvent(ApiRequestHandler.groovy:67)
    at com.mikebuyshouses.dncscrubber.awsServices.ApiRequestHandler$parseRequestEvent.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at com.mikebuyshouses.dncscrubber.awsServices.ApiRequestHandler.handleRequest(ApiRequestHandler.groovy:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The file utils method from my code base, that it is complaining about, that was otherwise working, is defined thus:

```
public static File CreateFileIfNotExists(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        File parentDirectory = file.getParentFile();
        if (parentDirectory == null)
            parentDirectory = new File('..')

        parentDirectory.mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    return file;
}
```

I installed AWS Toolkit to my IntelliJ IDEA, gave it all rights, and tried to use it to **debug** but to no avail.

I copy the multipart request that I copied from Postman, tried to send that request via the Toolkit, but it complained, as apparently it was expecting JSON request.

Here's the multipart request that I tried to send it (it was pieced together from multipart request I sent via Postman):

```
POST /test_1_0/lists HTTP/1.1
Host:[personal AWS Gateway subdomain here...].execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPHU848zA1KdI8ky9
Postman-Token:647fee68-fd6b-484f-aeed-6900905d5baa
User-Agent:PostmanRuntime/7.33.0
X-Amzn-Trace-Id:Root=1-652151b6-16c8e4a3065b346e48942950
X-Forwarded-For:[IP address]
X-Forwarded-Port:443
X-Forwarded-Proto:http

------WebKitFormBoundaryPHU848zA1KdI8ky9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="inputFile"; filename="test.csv"\r
Content-Type: text/csv\r
\r
[csv file contents here...]\r
\r------WebKitFormBoundaryPHU848zA1KdI8ky9\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="outputFileExtension"\r\n\r\n"XLSX"\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryPHU848zA1KdI8ky9--\r\n
```

Here's the error message I face when I hit OK:

```
Invoking Lambda function: dncScrbberLambda
Error invoking Lambda: Could not parse request body into json: Could not parse payload into json: Unrecognized token 'POST': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"POST /test_1_0/lists HTTP/1.1
[request details here...]
```

How am I supposed to **send `multipart/form-data` request**, so that I can **debug the Lambda locally**?

**DISCLAIMER**: I have *not* installed AWS SAM, CLI, or Docker onto my computer yet. I don't even know how to use those... :'(

Comment: 'it doesn't work' - does your computer vanish? point being, can you please share more information on the request? what's the actual issue here? you've not given the problem.

Comment: It was purely a code, namely a "the file you're tryna create doesn't exist" exception.

Comment: Well, you need to update your full question. Check CloudWatch logs and see what he issue is. What's the HTTP status code? There's 100000000 factors that could be at play here.

Comment: That's the point...I found the Exception, and the stack trace, from reading the CloudWatch logs, which prompts me to debug the app as an AWS Lambda function

Comment: I put in the details. I want to send multipart request to my Lambda Function, via AWS toolkit, in debug mode.

I don't want to end up having to leak my source code on here, and have some AI system steal, I mean "learn from", it